# Deploy .NET framework 4.5.x application using mono build pack on cloud foundry

Tags: .net, mono, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy .NET Framework 4.5.x or 4.6.x Console and MVC applications on cloud foundry using mono build.

I have used the following command for console app to push the in cloud foundry. The command for MVC is similar except app name changes:

*cf push consoleapp -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/.net-buildpack*

Its failing while starting instance of the application in CF.

The log says:

OUT App instance exited with guid f29a094f-7221-4e2b-aa1e-44e18d13bdde payload: {"instance"=>"", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* 2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* Codependent step exited\n* cancelled\n* cancelled", "crash_count"=>2, "crash_timestamp"=>1470654617839293652, "version"=>"d1d8a828-b108-4973-a8fa-d149ec4be388"}

Any clues?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the bleeding edge world of .NET and CF. We have successfully deployed .NET Core applications and are now actively researching whether it is or will be possible to deploy applications that have dependencies on the full framework. Hope that by starting this thread you help the community find a solution to this.